# Changing sprites on trigger collision

Tags: sprites

Sitting here at a game jam trying to make a game where i need to change a sprite when the ball hits a trigger. If anyone could help me with some of the coding needed you would have my sincerest thanks.

Comment: What Framework? What Language or anything? Because a "sprite" is a fairly abstract concept and its implementation (and therefore the way to change it) varies widely

Answer (score 0):

check this out: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/11/5/collision-detection-skphysicscontactdelegate

was not so hard to find: google for spritekit collision